# Compare 2 jSON files with same objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get, getjson

So I have 2 jSON files, both with same set up and same objects, difference is one has old data that is not updated, the other one has real-time data that is updated in real time, I'd like to subtract the old data with the new data, and output the result.

Code I used that ISN'T successful:

```
jQuery.getJSON(liveDataURL, function(liveData){

    jQuery.getJSON(oldDataURL, function(oldData){

        liveData.sort(function(a, b){
             return a.number - b.number;
        }).reverse();
        oldData.sort(function(a, b){
             return a.number - b.number; 
        }).reverse();

        var newList = liveData.number - oldData.number;
        console.log(newList);
    });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by subtract?

a = {foo: 17, bar: 12, baz: false}
b = {foo: 17, bar: 10}

what does "a - b" mean?

Assuming:

"a - b" := {bar: 12, baz: false}

Something like this will work:

```
const delta = (a, b) => {
  const d = {};
  Object.keys(a).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof a[key] === 'object') {
      d[key] = delta(a[key], b[key] || {});
      if (d[key] === undefined) {
        delete d[key];
      }
    } else {
      if (a[key] !== b[key]) {
        d[key] = a[key];
      }
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(d).length ? d : undefined;
};
```

Comment: My solution does not handle arrays :-) — exercise for the reader.

Comment: "return a.number - b.number" This returns a filtered result that shows the one with the highest number first. I am using it to sort the list for me with the highest amount first, I then want to subtract the results of the 2 lists from each other.

Answer (score -1):

```
var newList = liveData.number - oldData.number;
```

This is the wrong way to find difference between list.
Just do this, if you want to find the difference of numbers

Assuming the length of both list is same.

```
var newList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < liveData.length; i++){
    newList.append(liveData[i].number - oldData[i].number);
}
```